# Do These Spots On My Roof Need Repair?

Tags: roof, roofing, damage, shingles, wind

We had a new roof put on a few months ago.

The other week, we had a day with very strong winds. I went up on the roof today to check that everything was ok. Saw a few spots.

Don't know if these are from the wind, but do any of these spots warrant a repair?

And if so, do I need to tarp over that split shingle until we can fix it(have some light rain coming up)?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're showing us in the photos with the hand. The critical area is underexposed.

Comment: The photos with the hand were meant to show that the edges of certain shingles had come up a bit with the wind.  I was pulling them up to show the gap.   Will shingles like these lay back down and re-adhere w the sun?

Comment: You might revise to clear that up. Jack addressed the issue nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those places should warrant any concern. If you are in a cooler climate this time of year, the roofing has not had much of a chance to heat up the seal the shingles down.

The one with the split as you call it, is just an edge rolled under exposing a bit more of the shingle below it than normal. This could be rolled back out, and when it warms up, it will seal like the rest of the shingles. The nearest joint I see the that spot, looks to be about a 1 foot or more away. No concern there.

I see a bit of scuffing on the edges, which says a lot of traffice was in places or the shingles were treated roughly, before being laid. Even with that, that hardly has any effect on the longevity of the whole shingle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I live in Southern California - so a pretty mild winter.  Gotten up into the seventies the last couple of weeks. 

You’re saying that first pic with the circled area isn’t a split, and it’s just rolled up?  It felt pretty flat, and I could see that little silver strip underneath.  I’ll double check it.  I though it was maybe a defective or torn up architectural shingle.

Comment: I generally agree, but the first photo shows a sloppy cut on the end shingle, not a rollover. If the roofers are back for anything else I'd ask for that shingle to be replaced, if only for better appearance.

Comment: @isherwood It could be a sloppy cut. The edge where the shingle doubled over looked like it was a bit thicker due to the doubled layer there. It is minor. It would not hurt to get the roofer out there if it is a bad cut. But the only OP can determine if it is a bad cut or a folded edge with the shingle tucked under the rest.

Comment: I think it is indeed a sloppy cut and not doubled over on that first picture.  Assuming replacing that shingle would be for aesthetic reasons and not because it’s going to cause a leak?

Comment: No I don't see that being the cause of a leak in the future. The shingle extends 7 or more inches above the bad cut. The only thing that would possibly give reason for a leak there is a roofing nail being within 4" of the bad cut. Typically all nails should be that far away from any joint in any place on the roof. This is something roofers should be aware of at all times. If not, they have no business calling themselves roofers.